# Typescript interface array must implement a base interface

Tags: typescript, interface

How do I have a declaration inside an interface that enforces an object to extend another?

Scenario:
I receive a JSON object (called document) where the document.children is an array of objects that will always have _id, _ref and _type, as well as additional fields that are specific to its _type.

Currently There are 4 different types but this will grow and ideally i don't want future devs having to worry about editing the Document interface

```
export interface BaseRefs {
  _id: string;
  _ref: string;
  _type: string;
}

export interface Span extends BaseRefs {
  text: string;
}

export interface MainImage extends BaseRefs {
  url: string;
  caption: string;
}

export interface Document extends BaseRefs {
  _createdAt: string;
  _rev: string;
  _updatedAt: string;
  children: // Any object that extends BaseRefs
  // children: MainImage | Span | Carousel | ........ | Video[] // This is not ideal
}

export const document: Document = {
  _createdAt: '2019-12-12T04:14:18Z',
  _id: 'c9b9-4cd0-a281-f6010f5889fd',
  _ref: 'ej2gcz5m4',
  _rev: 'nwyfsi--ej2gcz5m4',
  _type: 'post',
  _updatedAt: '2020-01-16T11:22:32Z',
  children: [
    {
      _type: 'span',
      text: 'The rain in Spain',
    },
    {
      _type: 'mainImage',
      url: 'https://example.com/kittens.png',
    },
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I have a declaration inside an interface that enforces an object to extend another?

You can't do that *literally*. TypeScript's type system is *structural*, not *nominal*. You can require that it have all the properties defined by `BaseRefs`, but not that it actually `extends` `BaseRefs`.

As far as I can tell, the type of `children` should be `BaseRefs[]`:

```typescript
export interface Document extends BaseRefs {
  _createdAt: string;
  _rev: string;
  _updatedAt: string;
  children: BaseRefs[];
}
```

That requires that the elements in `children` all have all of the properties defined by `BaseRefs`. They can have *more* properties, so `Span` and `MainImage` and such are fine, but they must at least have the properties defined for `BaseRefs`.

That means you can safely use `_id`, `_ref`, and `_type` on elements in `children`, but if you try to use something else (like `Span`'s `text` property), TypeScript will complain that there is no `text` property on `BaseRefs`.

```typescript
for (const child of someDocument.children) {
    console.log(child.text);
    //                ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− error here
}
```

That's because the `child` may not be a `Span` or, more generally, may not have a `text` property.

You gain access to the property by using a *type guard*. One kind of type guard is a *type guard function*, which looks like this:

```typescript
function isSpan(x: BaseRefs): x is Span {
    return "text" in x;
}
```

Then:

```typescript
for (const child of someDocument.children) {
    if (isSpan(child)) {
        console.log(child.text);
        //                ^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− works
    }
}
```